# SQL Query based on URL

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql query which brings back information based on the Sessions Cookie.

I want to make a link to a users profile and have a url like account.php?id=Danny
Then i want to run a sql query but pass through the bit after the ?id=

My current SQL query

```
SELECT id,firstname,lastname,usr,admin,email,car 
FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_SESSION['usr']}'"
```

I want to make it get the username from the url

Comment: beware of sql injection attacks!

Comment: Voting to close because issues with specific pieces of code are on-topic at StackOverflow, but I'm not sure this would meet their quality standards so I don't want to vote to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

You get variables passed through the url with `$_GET`. So

```
$user = $_GET['id'];
//check $user variable to avoid sql injections

$sql = "SELECT id,firstname,lastname,usr,admin,email,car FROM tz_members WHERE usr='".$user."'
```